# Group and sort objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort an object which you can see below. I want to add all the `rating` properties for each object and sort the object depending on which rating is highest.

So for example, if `Intro 1` total rating is equal to 7 and `Intro 2` total rating is equal to 3, then `Intro 1` should be the first object.

```
{
  'Intro 2': [
    {
      deckName: 'Test 2',
      rating: 1
    },
    {
      deckName: 'Test 2',
      rating: 2
    }
  ],
  'Intro 1': [
    {
      deckName: 'Test 1',
      rating: 3
    },
    {
      deckName: 'Test 1',
      rating: 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Can you tell me what you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your data

```
const data = {
  "Intro 2": [
    {
      deckName: "Test 2",
      rating: 1
    },
    {
      deckName: "Test 2",
      rating: 2
    }
  ],
  "Intro 1": [
    {
      deckName: "Test 1",
      rating: 3
    },
    {
      deckName: "Test 1",
      rating: 4
    }
  ]
};
```

Let's convert it into array and sort through

```
const dataArr = Object.entries(data);

const sorted = dataArr.sort(
  (a, b) =>
    b[1].reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return acc + curr.rating;
    }, 0) -
    a[1].reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return acc + curr.rating;
    }, 0)
);
```

And finally converting the array back to object

```
const obj = {};

sorted.forEach((item) => {
  obj[item[0]] = item[1];
});
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-ramanujan-dwzwjm?file=/src/index.js

**UPDATE** 
For the last cycle of converting array to object, this can be more elegant solution

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(sorted);
```

Comment: Instead of the last cycle, to convert your array into an object, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). For example: `const obj = Object.fromEntries(sorted);`

Comment: nice, thanks for pointing out